# Single cyclic iteration from middle of rust vector

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a vector of some elements that I would like to iterate from some index and cycle around from the front again while only visiting each element a single time.

Ex. starting here at index *2*,

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
       ^
```

I would like to have an iterator over the elements [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1] (and avoid writing a loop everywhere I need to run through the vector this way).
The standard iteration with [cycle()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cycle) + [skip()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) seemed to be a good start, but it of cause never ends.

Is there any idiomatic way with rusts standard iterators?

Comment: Why not just slice and use `Iterator::chain` to join the two halves? e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=16cee881bd70ef5675e5caa6f89872d9

Comment: Maybe `.cycle().skip().take(v.len())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious fix for your cycle/skip combo is to add a `take()` to limit it:

```
fn cycle<T>(slice: &[T], start_pos: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
    slice.iter().cycle().skip(start_pos).take(slice.len())
}
```

Another option is to just chain the two ranges, which even ends up a bit shorter:

```
fn cycle<T>(slice: &[T], start_pos: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
    slice[start_pos..].iter().chain(&slice[..start_pos])
}
```

Both versions pass test such as:

```
let v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
assert_eq!(cycle(&v, 2).copied().collect::<Vec<_>>(), vec![2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1]);
```

Comment: There is very little overhead in the `cycle().skip().take()` solution. The `Iter` type for a slice spcial-cases `nth()` (used by the default implementation of `skip()`), so it doesn't need to loop, and `Cycle` has an intelligent implementation of `advance_by()` (used by the default implementation of `nth()`). The overhead does not depend on the actual indices at all – it's constant, and the compiler might even be able to eliminate it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I didn't know about the nth/skip optimization, thanks for pointing it out. I've edited the claim about unnecessary calls to next() out of the answer.

Comment: @user4815162342 I really like the first solution. And yes - it seems so obvious now that you pointed out to use `take() ` :-)  In the end I also needed to add an `enumerate()` to it with the "original" indices and that works will together.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the two subslices, and use `chain` to concatenate them together into a single iterator:

```
let v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let start_index = 2;
for e in v[start_index..].iter().chain(v[..start_index].iter()) {
    println!("{}", e);
}
```